Workspace keyboard switching has stopped working
I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, gnome desktop, and recently my workspace keyboard switching has stopped working.  I've checked my gnome settings and they look good
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up ['Page_Up', 'Up']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down ['Page_Down', 'Down']
but those keyboard actions now have no effect.  Any suggestions on how to fix?
thanks, Mitchell

GNOME version? [edit] in to your answer. By default to switch workspaces Ctrl + Alt + → to move right and Shift + Super + → to place the current window in the next workspace right. ← Home, End, Page Up Page Down work in a similar fashion.
